# identifying the user who called a web service

Tags: java, web-services, security

I have a web service and need to set results based on the caller's id.

It is tempting to define the interface on the server as:

```
public String[] getUserLogFile(int userId){
    return logDAO.getLogs(userId);
}
```

At log in, the web service returns a userId.  The client can include this userId on future calls.  However, if the client sets their own userId, the caller can try other userId's.  This presents security issues.

What is the best method to identify the caller of a web service?  Server is in Java.  Client can be an iPad, .Net, Android, etc.

Thanks. J.

Comment: Just have the clients set up a password with the Id.

Comment: This is way to broad of a topic to be covered by a single question. You might want to do some research, experiment with some code, then come back to SO if you run into problems. But crux of the matter is that you will need the caller to include a form of credentials that prove they are who they say they are - be it a hashed password, a public certificate, some kind of biometric. Etc ec. What technologies are you using?

Comment: the userid should be a session variable, and never attacker controlled

Comment: Perception, I've thought of passing a hash to the client.  Then the client can use the hash value in every web service call to uniquely identify the source.  I can code this up easily.  However, there should be an industry standard way of handling this.  Anyone who has coded a web service for getMyPurchaseOrders(), getMyBankAccountBalance(), etc. has faced this question. 
I'm JBoss/Sql Server on the server.  Client can be anything. (with a web service, isn't the idea to be platform independent?)

Comment: A server generated hash is not particularly secure, it's vulnerable to session spoofing and man-in-the-middle attacks. There are ***several*** industry and ever-evolving standards for security. That's one of the reasons I asked you what tech you are using, it helps to narrow the field.

Answer (score 1):

A simple but effective security strategy is to secure your web services with SSL, then pass a [basic authentication header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) on each call. The SSL part of this setup is ***critical***. Your client would include, in each call, an authorization header of the form:

> Authorization: Basic QWxhZGluOnNlc2FtIG9wZW4=

The encoded string is concatenation of username and password, base 64 encoded

```
Base64(username:password)
```

This takes care of the client side responsibilities. On the server side, you want to examine all incoming calls for the authorization header. If present, decode it, split username and password, and use those two pieces of information to authenticate the request. It is typical to create a security principal for the user upon authentication, containing basic information about the user and their roles (or application authorizations). For efficiency, this work is normally done in a web filter. I would recommend the following libraries which automate a lot of the server side tasks for you:

- [Seam Security](http://www.seamframework.org/Seam3/SecurityModule) (built into JBoss AS 7)
- [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/)
- [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/)